# Disable the default username in the registration form

Tags: forms, users

I just installed and configured the logintoboggan module; I created extra fields and they are displayed just fine. I can't remember how to disable the drupal default username field on the registration form.

Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable a field in a form you must use hook_form_alter() like

```
MYMODULE_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' ) { // id of registration form
    $form['account']['name']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

> *#access*
>
> Used by: All elements and forms
>
> Description: Whether the element is accessible or not; when FALSE, the
>   element is not rendered and the user submitted value is not taken into
>   consideration.

I would also like to mention for other people reading this that this can also be accomplished with the [email_registration](http://drupal.org/project/email_registration) module

Comment: can u please let me know how can remove or disable username from registration form using email_registration module.